# PHP Array to JSON - Array Formation Help Needed

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-maps-api-3, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a json feed for google maps API.

The JSON feed I can generate is:

```
 [{"latitude":"40.651602","longitude":"-111.918734","title":"64439","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"41.330500","longitude":"-111.851600","title":"80283","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.624500","longitude":"-111.976500","title":"95964","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.715020","longitude":"-111.494717","title":"96995","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.664200","longitude":"-111.843295","title":"101724","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.513917","longitude":"-111.403612","title":"245697","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.509000","longitude":"-111.419919","title":"245716","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.473700","longitude":"-111.414499","title":"245742","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.509943","longitude":"-111.402999","title":"245792","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.512200","longitude":"-111.477263","title":"245874","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.526623","longitude":"-111.475199","title":"245904","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.530400","longitude":"-111.487500","title":"245905","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.526619","longitude":"-111.473531","title":"245921","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.517013","longitude":"-111.487827","title":"245926","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.519500","longitude":"-111.497780","title":"245940","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.511981","longitude":"-111.409799","title":"245944","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"39.373348","longitude":"-111.574996","title":"245946","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.514900","longitude":"-111.402590","title":"245982","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.513700","longitude":"-111.467712","title":"246093","content":"test"}][{"latitude":"40.515600","longitude":"-111.398192","title":"246124","content":"test"}]
```

The code that generates this feed is:

```
while($data = $do->FetchRow($search)) {
    //print_r($data);
    $a = array();
    $a[] = array("latitude" => $data['latitude'], "longitude" => $data['longitude'], "title" => $data['listno'], "content" => "test");

    echo json_encode($a);
    //echo json_encode(array("markers" => $a), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
```

What I need, is for the array to be generated looking like this:

```
var json = [{"title":"Helgelandskysten","longitude":"12.63376","latitude":"66.02219"},{"title":"Tysfjord","longitude":"16.50279","latitude":"68.03515"},{"title":"Sledehunds-ekspedisjon","longitude":"7.53744","latitude":"60.08929"},{"title":"Amundsens sydpolferd","longitude":"11.38411","latitude":"62.57481"},{"title":"Vikingtokt","longitude":"6.96781","latitude":"60.96335"},{"title":"Tungtvann- sabotasjen","longitude":"8.49139","latitude":"59.87111"}];
```

I have tried playing around with array merges, array pushes, and more. I'm stumped, anybody want a good puzzle? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay there are a couple of issue with what you're doing. First off, you're echoing a json-encoded string for EACH seperate row, because you're calling it inside the loop. That is why you end up with several [] arrays in the generated string.

What you need to do is:

```
$a = array();
while($data = $do->FetchRow($search)) {
   $a[] = array("latitude" => $data['latitude'], "longitude" => $data['longitude'], "title" => $data['listno']);
}
echo json_encode($a);
```

Also, you're getting a number instead of the title that you want. I cannot help you there directly, but you're using:

```
$data['listno']
```

as title, which i assume actually stands for "list number". You're most likely going to have to either use the field "title" (if it exists) or revise your search query.

Comment: This fixed the array! Thank you. Interesting enough, google maps is not populating lol. The code works on somebody elses server, but somehow not on mine. Interesting

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, this is very hard to really respond to. If this persists, you should open another question. I'm happy your array issues were fixed though.

Comment: No worries. If I need help with maps, I will open up a new question, since you have rightfully answered this one, I would feel bad tacking more onto this!

Answer (score 1):

Just :

```
echo json_encode(array("latitude" => $data['latitude'], "longitude" => $data['longitude'], "title" => $data['listno'], "content" => "test"));
```

It will be enought since you have only 1 row I guess.

Comment: If I do that, it gives me this: